# Hippydrome-Rig in Blender: What components to use?

Tags: rigging

I have been reading the "Art of Moving Points" iBook by Brian Tindall which goes into great detail about setting up facial and other rigging systems. 
The deformation demos on his site are really perfect and smooth, so I am trying to get the same action going. http://hippydrome.com/

[image: Hippydrome Rigging Principles on Full Body]
[image: Skeleton Parts to Help Visualize Hard and Soft Parts]
[image: Rigging Facial Features with Seperated Avars]

I am having problems translating his instructions into Blender's rigging system.

Has anybody built a Hippydrome Rig in Blender yet?

Let me add a little bit of information on how the setup is supposed to work:

The basic idea is to seperate an object, like for instance, a face, into several zones. You then take those zones and split them into an outer, a middle and an inner zone.

You then create a system of layered control for each of thses zones. These are created to be fired one after the other in an effort to make rigs and animation date re-usable and the rigging process easier to debug.

Using an eye-lid as an example, you would split it up into three zones,

- outer
- middle
- inner

Then you would make separate controls for all possible movement direction of that section, each isolated into a single direction

- Up/Down
- Left/Right
- Twist
- Forward/Backward

Here is his video demo on that.
https://vimeo.com/144022577

Up to this point, there is no problem recreating the setup for me, this can easily be achieved with Shape Keys and Drivers.

The next Layer has me scratching my head, though, because this deals with the sculptural changes in the motion, basically, making sure, the points don't just move up or down, but follow the shape of the model. So for an eyelid, you would need something like a Rotation Deformer to move the lid points along the surface of the eyeball. And this is where I don't know what to do with the shapekeys anymore.

Theoretically, after adding the deformers, there would be a fourth layer on top of that, basically a corrective Shape Key that would add final fine changes to the mesh.

I am now wondering, how do I go about this? Do I need to start with Bones and Drivers instead of Shape Keys? Can I get motions along curves to work in blender at all?

Comment: Ok. I have located an example that uses multiple Armature Modifiers to take the sliding motion of one deformer, like a Shape Key and then moving it along either a curved path, or, using a bone, rotate it.
Here is Rene's explanation video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8uV-H59tpDg

I have never before used an Armature Modifier, but I will give it a shot und update with the results.